# Configure chromium display on a pseudo-headless Raspbian

Tags: gui, web-browsers

I'm using my raspi as a mini meteo station which (for now) only measure humidity and temperature, and I want it to display those infos on a little screen. Considering technologies I can handle, the appropriate way would be to launch a web browser in full screen, pointing to a localhost project.

Basically, I'm trying to reproduce something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487488/how-to-open-chromium-in-full-screen-kiosk-mode-in-minimal-windows-manager-enviro) or [this](https://www.ketzler.de/2017/12/installing-chromium-on-raspberry-pi-without-desktop/).

The screen is connected on the HDMI port and I'm connecting to the rpi by SSH (KiTTY for Windows 10). Since I only installed some GUI packages (mostly `xorg` and `openbox` I think) on a headless rpi, it boots on the CLI which displays perfectly on the screen. I use my rpi as a server and for some hobbyist domotic so installing a full GUI environment would be an overkill. Besides, I know this can be done and I'd like to improve my little understanding of the rpi's linux.

After hours of research, I came to launch the following script with the command `startx ~/my_project/start_chromium.sh`.

**start_chromium.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
chromium-browser --app=http://localhost --start-fullscreen
```

Despite the browser successfully displaying my HTML `hello world`, I have two big problems here:

1. this only works if I run the script from the rpi CLI (I plugged a keyboard to try), and not from the SSH, even with sudo (it says that `parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)`). I still can stop it with `pkill x` from the SSH though. I'm logged as `pi` on both Pi and SSH.
2. the window only takes half the screen width but all the available height. I uncommented `hdmi_safe=1` in `/boot/config.txt` and rebooted, and the windows was full-screen, but with a crappy little resolution. I'm not sure it comes from chromium or some lower-level windows managing.

I installed quite a bunch of packages (I cannot remember the whole list) during my research of a solution so I hope it didn't mess around the config, but I'm a bit scared to lose other stuff if I restart from scratch.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** (with links that didn't really helped me, but it could be because I don't really know everything I am doing)

- `exec openbox` throws the message "Openbox-Message: Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment variable" like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=155341) and event reboot the CLI (`.bash_profile` is ran). If I run this after the `startx` call it only adds a top bar to my chromium windows.
- `sudo Xorg -configure` lists 8 video drivers and says that there is "No devices to configure. Configuration failed" like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=180032). There is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.